# Is it possible to apply AVAssetExport on remote URL?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

In my swift app, I am doing the following:

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL)
// Add watermarking filter         
let watermarkFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceOverCompositing")!
//Export session
```

This works when URL is local with `AVAsset` but fails when URL is remote. Is it possible to make it work with remote URL?

Error I get:

```
  - some : Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSUnderlyingError=0x2801b07e0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12109 "(null)"}}
```